# Apache echart showing y1 axis without configure

Tags: echarts

am implemented **apache e-chart** on my angular project.Am configured both **X** and **Y** axis.
When i change grid left value to -10 or 0 it will show the **Y1** axis like below.
[image]

Do we have any options for hide or remove the highlighted **Y1** axis.

Expecting a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

am missed to add position on the yAxis confguration

```
position:'left'
```

issue resolved.